# Split screen with a singe shortcut(without using super + left or right)

Tags: screen, split

So I want to split the screen into two applications with one single keystroke. For example, I have Chrome and VSCode running, and I would love to press super + s so it automatically splits the screen into two. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: So how is that supposed to behave if you have three or more application windows open?

Comment: Split the last two windows that were open

Comment: There is probably no easy way to do this in Gnome Shell and any stacking window manager. I imagine it might be possible with some scripting with tools such as xdotool and xprop, but then only if you are running on Xorg. Tiling Window managers such as i3 do that without any keypress

Comment: @vanadium that's sad. but thanks for answering!